# Nested JSON parsing in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

My JSON is given below. I want to use 2ndCol, 3rdCol, 4thCol which are in rows.

```
{  

   "workflows":[  
      {  
         "New":{  
            "All":{  
               "sections":[  
                  {  
                     "id":"section_1",
                     "section":"",
                     "title":"SEPG Audit Checklist",
                     "rows":[  
                        {  
                            "id" : "0",
                            "label" : "How do you establish and maintain the description of the process needs and objectives for the organization?",
                            "2ndCol" : {
                                "type" : "select",
                                "source":[  
                                      {  
                                         "id":"Yes",
                                         "value":"Yes"
                                      },
                                      {  
                                         "id":"No",
                                         "value":"No"
                                      },
                                      {  
                                         "id":"N/A",
                                         "value":"N/A"
                                      }
                                ],
                                "value":[],
                                "required":true,
                                "disabled":false,
                                "hidden":false
                            },
                            "3rdCol" : {
                                "type" : "select",
                                "source":[  
                                      {  
                                         "id":"Yes",
                                         "value":"Yes"
                                      },
                                      {  
                                         "id":"No",
                                         "value":"No"
                                      }

                                ],
                                "value":[],
                                "required":true,
                                "disabled":false,
                                "hidden":false
                            },
                            "4thCol" : {
                                "type" : "textarea",
                                "label": "Comments",
                                "PlaceHolder":"Enter Comment",
                                "Value":""
                            }
                        },
                        {  
                            "id" : "1",
                            "label" : "Explain Organizational process performance objectives?",
                            "2ndCol" : {
                                "type" : "select",
                                "source":[  
                                      {  
                                         "id":"Yes",
                                         "value":"Yes"
                                      },
                                      {  
                                         "id":"No",
                                         "value":"No"
                                      },
                                      {  
                                         "id":"N/A",
                                         "value":"N/A"
                                      }
                                ],
                                "value":[],
                                "required":true,
                                "disabled":false,
                                "hidden":false
                            },
                            "3rdCol" : {
                                "type" : "select",
                                "source":[  
                                      {  
                                         "id":"Yes",
                                         "value":"Yes"
                                      },
                                      {  
                                         "id":"No",
                                         "value":"No"
                                      }

                                ],
                                "value":[],
                                "required":true,
                                "disabled":false,
                                "hidden":false
                            },
                            "4thCol" : {
                                "type" : "textarea",
                                "label": "Comments",
                                "PlaceHolder":"Enter Comment",
                                "Value":""
                            }
                        }
                         ]
                  }
               ]

            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I can use id, label of the rows. But when i am trying to use 2ndCol , 3rdCol and 4thCol in rows . It shows uncaught exception illegal argument.

My angular controller,

```
angular.forEach($scope.auditJSON.workflows, function(workflow, workflowIndex) {
                    angular.forEach(workflow, function(workflowValue, workflowKey) {
                        angular.forEach(workflowValue, function(value, roleKey) {
                            angular.forEach(value.sections, function(section, sectionIndx) {
                                angular.forEach(section.rows, function(row, rowIndx) {  

                                    console.log(row.label); // It shows fine

                                    console.log(row.2ndCol.type); // It shows the Error

                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
```

I can't figure out the problems.

Comment: what are you trying to do with this? `ng-repeat` will do most of the looping for you

Comment: By using ng-repeat, i render the data in html. But i need the values of 2ndCol , 3rdCol in controller for other purposes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You write that you want to get the value of type of 2ndCol and 3rdCol [you write it in the comments ]

```
 console.log(row.2ndCol.type); // It shows the Error
```

You also write that shows error. 
I give blocks of code. That should work.

```
angular.forEach($scope.auditJSON.workflows, function(workflow, workflowIndex) {
                angular.forEach(workflow, function(workflowValue, workflowKey) {
                    angular.forEach(workflowValue, function(value, roleKey) {
                        angular.forEach(value.sections, function(section, sectionIndx) {
                            angular.forEach(section.rows, function(row, rowIndx) {  
                                    if(row['2ndCol'].type === 'select' && row['3rdCol'].type === 'select'){
                                        if(row['2ndCol'].value != row['3rdCol'].value){
                                            console.log(row['2ndCol'].value);
                                            console.log(row['3rdCol'].value);
                                        }
                                    }

                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
```

If it solve your problem, accept as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your `angular.forEach` are a bit messed up.

[image]

```
angular.forEach($scope.data, function (workflow, workflowIndex) {
        angular.forEach(workflow, function (workflowValue, workflowKey) {
            angular.forEach(workflowValue, function (value, roleKey) {
                angular.forEach(value, function (sections, sectionIndx) {
                    angular.forEach(sections, function (section, rowIndx) {
                        angular.forEach(section, function (row, rowIndx) {
                            angular.forEach(row, function (row, rowIndx) {
                                if (rowIndx === 'rows') {
                                    angular.forEach(row, function (row, rowIndx) {
                                        var row2 = row['2ndCol'];
                                        var row3 = row['3rdCol'];
                                        console.log(row2, row3);
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

I've actually had to create a repo so you can see how it works. Also please don't use that many `forEach`'s in your production!

EDIT:
https://github.com/eknowles/blank-ng/tree/29902467/nested-json-parsing-in-angular-js

Comment: Why is this row[0].rows here ?

Comment: I was just picking the first row as an example.

Comment: But i need  to dynamically pick all the rows.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but if you explain what you're trying to do it would be a lot easier

Comment: I need to read the value of 2ndCol and 3rdCol for comparing these.

Comment: You can use row['2ndCol'].value to get the value

Comment: That might work. Can you give code blocks together ?